# Law of the iterated logarithm for a Standard Brownian Motion (SBM)

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $(B_t)_{t\geq0}$ be a SBM, $a>0, b>0$, and $$\tau:=\inf\{t\geq0:B_t=b\sqrt{a+t}\}, (\inf\emptyset:=0).$$ I want to show that $\mathbb{P}(\tau<\infty)=1$ with the law of iterated logarithm for a SBM, but I don't know how to do it. I have a solution for it but i don't use it here the law of iterated logarithm for a SBM. So
$$ M_t:=\exp \left( \xi B_{\tau \wedge t}-\dfrac{1}{2}\xi^2t\wedge \tau\right), \quad\xi\in \mathbb{R}, $$
then
$$ \mathbb{E}(M_t)=\mathbb{E}(M_0)=\text{e}^{\xi x},$$
and
$$ \lim_{t\to\infty} \exp \left( \xi B_{\tau \wedge t}-\dfrac{1}{2}\xi^2t\wedge \tau\right) = \begin{cases}
     \exp\left(\xi B_\tau-\dfrac{1}{2}\tau\xi^2\right),&\text{if } \tau<\infty,\\
     0, & \text{if } \tau=\infty.
    \end{cases} $$
And if $\xi\to 0 \Longrightarrow   \mathbb{P}(\tau<\infty)=1$, where $t\wedge\tau:=\min\{t,\tau\}.$

Answer (score 2):

$\tau=\infty$ implies that $B_t \leq b\sqrt {a+t}$ for all $t$. This implies that $\frac {B_t} {\sqrt {t \log \log t}} \to 0$. But then $\lim \sup \frac {B_t} {\sqrt {t \log \log t}} =0$. LIL for SBM shows that this event has probability $0$. [ $P(\lim \sup \frac {B_t} {\sqrt {t \log \log t}} =1)=1$].